# Linux Mint Olivia doesn't detect HD4000 Intel graphic

Tags: linux-mint, graphics

I opened Mint after a week or so & soon welcomed by a notification saying something like 'CPU high usage will be experienced due to no Graphic module' i opened my system summary & instead of the previously written 'Ivy bridge controller' following was written
[image]
All of the graphic module are present none is being changed then what might be the problem. Several terminal outputs are posted following

#### inxi output

```
echo@echo ~ $ inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           X.Org: 1.13.3 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1440x900@59.9hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2 GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.1.4 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

#### glxinfo output

```
echo@echo ~ $ glxinfo
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.1.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_texture, 
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_ARB_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_S3_s3tc, 
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, 
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, 
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, 
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_float, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_MESA_texture_array, 
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_EXT_texture_snorm, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, 
    GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_texture_storage, 
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be sure to try everything suggested on this Arch Linux wiki page, titled: [Intel Graphics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics). There are several things to check, too numerous to list here.